# How to save allure report on another branch in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, playwright

Here is my .yml file:

```
  - testing
  - deploy 

docker_job:
  stage: testing
  tags:
    - docker
  image: atools/chrome-headless:java11-node14-latest 

  before_script:
    - npm ci 
    - npx playwright install
    - npm install allure-commandline --save-dev
  script:
    - npm run testfile
    
  after_script:
    - npx allure generate allure-results
  rules:
      - when: always
  allow_failure: false
  artifacts: 
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./allure-report
    expire_in: 1 day 

pages: 
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir public 
    - mv ./allure-report/* public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - when: always
```

and i'd like to save allure results and allure report folders in another branch on folder named "public", how can I do it? For example I have another branch with name "Pages".

And another question, if I will be able to store that reports on another branch, it means that I can also copy "history" folder from generated allure report, and the whole allure results to save the info about last CI runs, is it true?

If I am right, here is last one question: how can I save that artifacts for some N days, or expire_in option will delete old files automatically somehow?

Comment: Git is not designed to have files "go away": a commit is permanent (mostly—commits *can* be dropped, but it's painful and some hosting systems never drop them) and read-only (completely). So don't store temporary files in Git: Git is your permanent record. As for storing a report: you can do that, but remember that the GitLab CI system runs on a *temporary copy* of the repository. You can add a commit to this copy, but you must then *send* the commit *out* of the copy before the copy is removed at the end of the CI sequence.

Comment: It's much easier (and usually better) to store the build products—including reports—from a CI build as "build artifacts", since all CI systems already provide that as a basic function.